# spa proxy 7.0 exclude some path

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, single-page-application

While I'm using dotnet 7

when my project package not include Microsoft.AspNetCore.proxy , when I run it, it will provide error  Microsoft.AspNetCore.proxy not find, when I add back, I need to add

```
<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44414</SpaProxyServerUrl>
```

Right now the problem is, when do this,
I want to do in program.cs

`app.map.when (context=>!context.request.path.startwithSegments("/swagger"), { builder=> build.useSpa(...)})`

will not working, that mean I can't exclude some of path will not route to front end proxy server.
can I know any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude certain paths from being routed to the front-end proxy server, you can use the `MapWhen` middleware.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Exclude /swagger from being proxied.
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"), spaBranch =>
{
    spaBranch.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // Configure SPA if needed
    });
    
    // Use the proxy package here.
    spaBranch.RunProxy(new ProxyOptions 
    {
        Scheme = "https",
        Host = "localhost",
        Port = "44414"
    });
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: It didn't work when I add the package 
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.proxy

Comment: @CarrieKaski could you try updated code